# Can a SUN ALOM system (non-CMT) send SNMP traps?

Tags: nagios, sun, ilo, snmp

I configured Nagios to receive passive service checks via SNMP traps from SUN remote management boards (ILOM/ALOM in their slang).

This works great for ILOM-based SUN servers, but i couldn't find out if ALOM systems support sending SNMP traps. I know ALOM systems with CMT can.

Did anyone already do this or has experience with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i can read only ALOM CMT supports snmp traps directly.
Anyway you could do it passing through sunmc agent, as stated here:

http://wikis.sun.com/display/ASRSO/Sun+T1+T2

(read Advanced Lights Out Manager (ALOM) Requirements)

Hope this helps.